# How do I get Blender to export my rigged & animated FBX model correctly?

Tags: export, fbx

I have a model in FBX format.  It has rigging, textures, and a 226-frame animation.  The rigging and animation work correctly, but the textures don't.  I brought it into Blender and fixed the textures, but when I try to export it, it takes upwards of 5 minutes to export, and in other software, the animation is over 5,000 frames long, and none of the body parts move correctly; the entire mesh just swivels and rotates all over the workspace.

How do I get Blender to export exactly what I imported, with the changes to the material zones only?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  In the FBX export dialog, under "Bake Animation," I unchecked "Key All Bones", "NLA Strips", and "All Actions".  It worked fine after that.